# Logical Operators in Javascript

Tags: javascript, nested

I want to print out FizzBuzz when i is both divisible by 3 and by 5. What could be the problem with my code?

```
 for(var i = 1; i<=20; i++){

     if(i % 3 ===0){
         console.log("Fizz");
     }else if(i % 5 ===0){
         console.log("Buzz");
     }else if(i%3 ==0 && i%5 ==0){
         console.log("FizzBuzz");
     }else{
         console.log(i);
     }
}
```

Comment: Because the first condition that matches will execute, and nothing else will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first or second condition is true, it enters that block, but doesn't evaluate any of the other `else if` conditions. Because the third condition requires both the first and second to be true, there's no way it will ever enter that block.

Try arranging your conditions like this:

```
for(var i = 1; i<=20; i++){
     if(i%3 === 0 && i%5 === 0){
         console.log("FizzBuzz");
     }else if(i % 3 === 0){
         console.log("Fizz");
     }else if(i % 5 === 0){
         console.log("Buzz");
     }else{
         console.log(i);
     }
}
```

But just for fun, here's a much more compact version that abuses the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
for(var i = 1; i<=20; i++){
    console.log(i % 15 ? i % 5 ? i % 3 ? i : "Fizz" : "Buzz" : "FizzBuzz");
}
```

Comment: An even more compact (and efficient) solution that *uses* the conditional operator: `console.log((i%3?"":"Fizz")+(i%5?"":"Buzz")||i)`

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that your check for "FizzBuzz" doesn't happen until after your other comparisons. If `i % 3 === 0` (one of the requirements to print "FizzBuzz"), it will never *reach* the FizzBuzz check.

As a simple fix, move your FizzBuzz check to the first if-statement.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
     if(i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
         console.log("FizzBuzz");
     }
     else if(i % 5 === 0) {
         console.log("Buzz");
     }
     else if(i % 3 === 0) {
         console.log("FizzBuzz");
     }
     else {
         console.log(i);
     }
}
```

As another thing to think about, if i is divisible by both 3 and 5, then it is divisible by their least-common denominator, yes? The least common denominator (the smallest whole number that is divisible by a group of numbers) of 3 and 5 is 15, so you could replace...

```
if(i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {
```

...with...

```
if(i % 15 === 0) {
```

Comment: *then it is divisible by 15* => sure, but is 15 the greatest common divisor? In this case it is because 3 and 5 are both primes, but with nonprimes it would not necessarily work this way.

Comment: @Jon Do you mean the least-common denominator? And yes; it happens to be 3 * 5 because both are prime.

Comment: Yes, mindblock, sorry. LCD is correct instead of GCD. Just saying that some explanation of why that is equivalent would be helpful.

Comment: @Jon - Added a small explanation on LCD

Answer (score 0):

`(i%3 ==0 && i%5 ==0)` should be the first condition. If you think about it, if i is divisible by 3 and by 5 it will enter the first `if` statement before it reaches the third.